# Check if data exist update else insert in SQL Server linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I try to insert data from table in another. I want to check all rows, if row exists, just update, if row does not exist, insert it (based on `ID`).

I have this `insert` statement:

```
 insert into d1.dbo.UrlRecord (EntityId, EntityName, Slug, IsActive, LanguageId) 
     select 
         Id, 'Category', 
         REPLACE(Name, ' ', '-'), 1, 0 
     from d2.dbo.Category
```

if `Id` exist just update with new value else insert

I want to make it run dynamically using job in SQL Server

Comment: Heard about `MERGE` statements ?

Comment: Here you go **[MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb510625.aspx)**. Give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following MERGE script

```
MERGE d1.dbo.UrlRecord TT
USING      
(
SELECT 
Id,'Category' as EntityName,REPLACE(Name,' ','-') as Slug,1 as IsActive,0 as LanguageID
FROM d2.dbo.Category 
)ST on TT.EntityId = ST.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ( EntityId,EntityName,Slug,IsActive,LanguageId)
    VALUES (ST.Id,ST.EntityName,ST.Slug, ST.IsActive,ST.LanguageID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
    SET 
    TT.EntityName = ST.EntityName,
    TT.Slug = ST.Slug,
    TT.IsActive = ST.IsActive,
    TT.LanguageId=ST.LanguageID
    ;
```